# How to inject 10 files with parameter values to a selenium test and execute sequentially

Tags: selenium

I have a base test in SELENIUM where parameters are defined and i have 10 different set of values to test. Every time i have to manually change the test parameters and get the result. How to have a file which has 10 different values for scenarios and run each file on the same test and record the result. For ex :

I have a code

a+b = c, everytime manually i change the value for a=2 and b=3 and get the result 5. Now i want to have

filea has
2
3

fileb has
4
5

And after file a is injected to the test and executes with the values it should go to the second file and pick values and at the end it should display me for these parameter values this is result and it passed or failed.

Comment: Which language are you using, could you provide an example of what you have so far? Thanks.

Comment: i am using java and i cannot share the code for various reasons!

Answer (score 0):

do u use any testing frameworks like testng or junit ? if yes you can achieve your scenario using dataprovider.

say that you have a dataprovider method which will have all your different sets of input,

```
@dataprovider
public Object[][] getTestData(){
  return new Object[][]{ 
    {4,5},{3,2},{4,7}
  };
}
```

and you can map your test method to this dataprovider so that your test method will iterate through the data you have provided and executes for different input.

if you want to use only one set of data which changes each time you execute your tests, then there's a feature called as `parameters` with which you can specify the values in your suite file and use it in your test.